# What benefits do real numbers bring to the theory of rational numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, real-numbers

Complex numbers make it easier to find real solutions of real polynomial equations. Algebraic topology makes it easier to prove theorems of (very) elementary topology (e.g. the invariance of domain theorem).

In that sense, what are theorems purely about rational numbers whose proofs are greatly helped by the introduction of real numbers?

By "purely" I mean: not about Cauchy sequences, Dedekind cuts, etc. of rational numbers. (This is of course a meta-mathematical statement and therefore imprecise by nature.)

"No, there is no such thing, because..." would also be a valuable answer.

Comment: Does all of analytic number theory count?

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem, maybe ? :)

Comment: I sort of like having $\sqrt{2}$ around when confronted to some triangles.

Comment: What you say about complex numbers making the study of real polynomials neater is also true for rational polynomials: is you really want to understand why $X^2 - 1$ has two rational solutions but $X^2 - 2$ has none, I guess that real numbers will pop up quite organically :-)

Comment: A rational circle would benefit much from becoming a real circle.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this is a little trivial, but I consider the ability to rewrite $$A=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^2 < 2\}$$ as $$A=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : -\sqrt{2} <x<\sqrt{2}\}$$
to be a benefit.

The latter characterization makes the "structure" of this set much clearer; in particular, its suddenly clear why this set is convex, by which I mean that if $x,y \in A$, then for all $a \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $x<a<y$, we have $a \in A$.

Comment: I am not convinced by your last argument. If $a \geqslant 0$, then $a < y$ implies $a^2 < y^2 < 2$ and if $a < 0$, then $x < a$ implies $-a < -x$ whence $a^2 = (-a)^2 < (-x)^2 = x^2 < 2$. No real number needed.

Answer (score 2):

Real numbers together with all the other completions of the rationals known as the $p$-adics are very useful indeed in finding *rational* solutions of quadratic forms. A general principle known as [Hasse principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle) asserts that a quadratic form in $n$ variables has rational solutions if and only if it has solutions in each completion.